# ColorRamp on 3D Array

Tags: modifiers, color

How can I apply ColorRamp shader on an Array to get this effect?
Each corner has different color. White - Red - Green - Blue - Magenta - Cyan - Yellow.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Hello ! Please add more information about your setup, there are many ways to achieve this effect.

Comment: @Gorgious I tried this one https://snipboard.io/2cIiOm.jpg but when I apply it to an arrayed object it does not have the same falloff https://snipboard.io/KxmriB.jpg do you know why that is?

Comment: @Gorgious. I am running a MacStudio M1 Ultra with 128GB.

Answer (score 2):

Array is one object. Texture Coordinate node gives you object space vectors that can be displayed as color:

[image]

Colors can be remapped by simple Color Mix nodes:

[image]

The issue is that its a gradient and every array element is not solid color but a part of a gradient as well. You could get stepped gradient by rounding the coordinate values. Blender's Math node in Round mode is a bit funny - it only rounds to integers without the possibility to specify precision for rounding so you need to multiply and then divide the value by the same number to control precision to which you want to round, but that's OK:

[image]

So you could match the steps to the number of array elements if you wanted each element to have solid color you would probably need to shift the gradients a bit so the steps do not happen in the middle of your array elements by simply adding some value with math node.

Comment: Hi @Martynas I also tried my version https://snipboard.io/2cIiOm.jpg where it has this nice falloff but when I tried applying it on the entire array object it doesn't have the same gradual fade falloff from one color to the next https://snipboard.io/KxmriB.jpg Do you know why? Isn't it supposed to be the same since I used Object as texture coordinate space in both cases

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie it looks like your objects are way bigger than the ones in the answer (see the grid subdivisions) so you reach the color limits immediately. Try scaling your cubes in edit mode way down or playing with the scale of the mapping node

Comment: That's weird. [Exact same nodes work for me in Blender 3.4.0 on Windows](https://snipboard.io/IvdaXy.jpg). It's Object space so scale should not matter. A bug maybe?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys wow so my setup worked? i guess coz im running blender 3.4 on Windows 7. Hi \Gorgious yeah it is huge i think, i forgot but size shouldnt matter i think.

Comment: Very weird issue. I don't imagine any likely explanations to be honest.